# C what is a function specifier? like _inline _NORETURN

Tags: c, function, opencl, specifier

Today I started learning OpenCL when I came across function specifier like `_kernel`. Than I searched for it and I found many function specifier like `_inline` `_noreturn`. I want to know what is a function specifier and what's its usage? I have read many C programming books but never found such term?

```
_Noreturn
```

Is the above specifier similar to `void`?

Comment: Note that while `_inline` and `_noreturn` are actual C keywords, `_kernel` is an OpenCL define. It has nothing to do with your operating system's runtime -- in fact it runs on the graphics card.

Comment: @Blindy: Neither `_inline` nor `_noreturn` is a C keyword; the keywords are `inline` and `_Noreturn`.

Comment: That's semantics, they directly match. My point was that `_kernel` isn't in the same category as the OP implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a good link explaining function specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_specifiers)

I have quoted an excerpt that more accurately answers your specific question:

> _Noreturn (since C11) - specifies that the function does not return to where it was called from.

Answer (score 0):

You need a book familiar with C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011).  The keyword `_Noreturn` is a new function specifier, like `inline` (which was added in C99 or ISO/IEC 9899:1999).  It is not a type (or absence of type) as with `void`.  `_Noreturn` means that the function does not return.  For example, the C11 standard declares that `exit()` is a function that does not return:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
_Noreturn void exit(int status);
```

There's also a header, `<stdnoreturn.h>`, that provides

```
#define noreturn _Noreturn
```

Note that the name `_Noreturn` is from the namespace reserved for the implementation; the name `noreturn` could have been used by a user.  Any code broken by `_Noreturn` was already abusing the namespace reserved for the implementation.

You'll also find older code using compiler-specific mechanisms, such as `__attribute__((noreturn))` in GCC.

In general, function specifiers identify properties about a function that are not directly the type of the function.  For example, `inline` has implications that the function may be suitable for inlining — it is a hint to the compiler/optimizer.  Similarly, `_Noreturn` is a hint to the compiler/optimizer that if the function is called, control will never return to the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [full machine-readable C11 grammar (with GNU extensions)](https://github.com/o11c/nicate/blob/master/gram/gnu-c.gram).

Quoting the relevant parts here:

```
function-definition:
    declaration-specifiers_opt declarator declaration-list_opt compound-statement

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiers_opt
    function-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
    alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
    attributes declaration-specifiers_opt

function-specifier:
    inline
    _Noreturn
```

I would accept pull requests to add new grammars for other compilers/languages since I'm not aware of anyone else collecting them.